# How Verify X.509 Signature?

Tags: x509, sign

X.509 certificate has signature value.

I want to verify the signature in client certificate with public key of root CA or intermediate CA.

I know the information of both of them. But I don't know what messages needed.

I want to ask what's the messages needed to generate the signature value?

It only need Issuer information or Subject Name by hex? or is the issuer arbitrary when generating a certificate?

Comment: Depending on a OS/platform, you need to execute certificate chaining engine that does this validation.

Answer (score 0):

Verifying the signature is not sufficient, you need to validate the certificate chain and all of the associated policy constraints. In Windows / C you would use CertGetCertificateChain(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certgetcertificatechain), but each platform has its own approach to this problem. Its far more complicated than most realize (https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~shmat/shmat_ccs12.pdf) so please stick to platform APIs for this validation.